# How to Import-PSSession of vmware vcenter server connection session?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I need to vcenter server connection session in my script.. I have connect-VIServer cmdlet to get connect to vcenter server.. But i can't able to take and maintain session throughout the script. I need to reuse those vcenter server session..

```
$vcsession = Connect-VIServer -Server xxxx
Import-PSSession -Session $session
Import-PSSession : Cannot bind parameter 'Session'. Cannot convert the "xxxxx.xxx.com" value of type "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.VIServerImpl" to type "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession".

Enter-PSSession -Session $vcsession
Enter-PSSession : Cannot bind parameter 'Session'. Cannot convert the 
"xxxx.xxx.com" value of type 
"VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.VIServerImpl" to type "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession".

New-PSSession -Session $session.SessionSecret
New-PSSession : Cannot bind parameter 'Session'. Cannot convert the ""b4b7be33bcace66b284f60ed09c86d83e119f1ff"" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession".At line:1 char:24
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Connect-VIServer.html), the session is in the returned object of the `Connect-VIServer` cmdlet. You can reconnect using a previous session with `Connect-VIServer -Server xxxx -Session $vcsession.SessionId`

Comment: Thank u so much.. you saved my time.. @Theo.. Its working fine

Comment: Can't able to call the user-defined function after the session..